# No ServerProperties registered in AspectJ

Tags: spring, aspectj, spring-aop, pointcut

I am trying to create an advice that will be executed around all the public methods. This is my aspect, point cut expression is being referred from [Spring Docs](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/core.html#aop-pointcuts-combining)

```
@Aspect
@Component
public class SomeAspect {

    private final Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(this.getClass());

    @PostConstruct
    public void init() {
        log.warn("postconstruct");
    }

    @Pointcut("execution(public * *(..))")
    private void anyPublicOperation() {}

    @Before("anyPublicOperation()")
    public void logBefore() {
        log.info("@Before");
    }
}
```

I receive the following stack trace

```
2018-07-10 12:24:29.465  WARN 18748 --- [           main] ationConfigEmbeddedWebApplicationContext : Exception encountered during context initialization - cancelling refresh attempt: org.springframework.context.ApplicationContextException: Unable to start embedded container; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'tomcatEmbeddedServletContainerFactory' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/web/EmbeddedServletContainerAutoConfiguration$EmbeddedTomcat.class]: Initialization of bean failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: No ServerProperties registered
2018-07-10 12:24:29.473  INFO 18748 --- [           main] utoConfigurationReportLoggingInitializer : 

Error starting ApplicationContext. To display the auto-configuration report re-run your application with 'debug' enabled.
2018-07-10 12:24:29.485 ERROR 18748 --- [           main] o.s.boot.SpringApplication               : Application startup failed

org.springframework.context.ApplicationContextException: Unable to start embedded container; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'tomcatEmbeddedServletContainerFactory' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/web/EmbeddedServletContainerAutoConfiguration$EmbeddedTomcat.class]: Initialization of bean failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: No ServerProperties registered
    at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.onRefresh(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:137) ~[spring-boot-1.5.14.RELEASE.jar:1.5.14.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:537) ~[spring-context-4.3.18.RELEASE.jar:4.3.18.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.refresh(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:122) ~[spring-boot-1.5.14.RELEASE.jar:1.5.14.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:693) [spring-boot-1.5.14.RELEASE.jar:1.5.14.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:360) [spring-boot-1.5.14.RELEASE.jar:1.5.14.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:303) [spring-boot-1.5.14.RELEASE.jar:1.5.14.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1118) [spring-boot-1.5.14.RELEASE.jar:1.5.14.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1107) [spring-boot-1.5.14.RELEASE.jar:1.5.14.RELEASE]
    at some.example.SpringAopApplication.main(SpringAopApplication.java:12) [classes/:na]
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'tomcatEmbeddedServletContainerFactory' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/web/EmbeddedServletContainerAutoConfiguration$EmbeddedTomcat.class]: Initialization of bean failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: No ServerProperties registered
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:564) ~[spring-beans-4.3.18.RELEASE.jar:4.3.18.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:483) ~[spring-beans-4.3.18.RELEASE.jar:4.3.18.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:312) ~[spring-beans-4.3.18.RELEASE.jar:4.3.18.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230) ~[spring-beans-4.3.18.RELEASE.jar:4.3.18.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:308) ~[spring-beans-4.3.18.RELEASE.jar:4.3.18.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:202) ~[spring-beans-4.3.18.RELEASE.jar:4.3.18.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.getEmbeddedServletContainerFactory(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:199) ~[spring-boot-1.5.14.RELEASE.jar:1.5.14.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.createEmbeddedServletContainer(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:162) ~[spring-boot-1.5.14.RELEASE.jar:1.5.14.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.onRefresh(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:134) ~[spring-boot-1.5.14.RELEASE.jar:1.5.14.RELEASE]
    ... 8 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: No ServerProperties registered
    at org.springframework.util.Assert.state(Assert.java:70) ~[spring-core-4.3.18.RELEASE.jar:4.3.18.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.web.ServerPropertiesAutoConfiguration$DuplicateServerPropertiesDetector.customize(ServerPropertiesAutoConfiguration.java:84) ~[spring-boot-autoconfigure-1.5.14.RELEASE.jar:1.5.14.RELEASE]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_161]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:1.8.0_161]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:1.8.0_161]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) ~[na:1.8.0_161]
    at org.springframework.aop.support.AopUtils.invokeJoinpointUsingReflection(AopUtils.java:333) ~[spring-aop-4.3.18.RELEASE.jar:4.3.18.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:190) ~[spring-aop-4.3.18.RELEASE.jar:4.3.18.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:157) ~[spring-aop-4.3.18.RELEASE.jar:4.3.18.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.adapter.MethodBeforeAdviceInterceptor.invoke(MethodBeforeAdviceInterceptor.java:52) ~[spring-aop-4.3.18.RELEASE.jar:4.3.18.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179) ~[spring-aop-4.3.18.RELEASE.jar:4.3.18.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.interceptor.ExposeInvocationInterceptor.invoke(ExposeInvocationInterceptor.java:92) ~[spring-aop-4.3.18.RELEASE.jar:4.3.18.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179) ~[spring-aop-4.3.18.RELEASE.jar:4.3.18.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:213) ~[spring-aop-4.3.18.RELEASE.jar:4.3.18.RELEASE]
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy61.customize(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
    at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedServletContainerCustomizerBeanPostProcessor.postProcessBeforeInitialization(EmbeddedServletContainerCustomizerBeanPostProcessor.java:73) ~[spring-boot-1.5.14.RELEASE.jar:1.5.14.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedServletContainerCustomizerBeanPostProcessor.postProcessBeforeInitialization(EmbeddedServletContainerCustomizerBeanPostProcessor.java:59) ~[spring-boot-1.5.14.RELEASE.jar:1.5.14.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.applyBeanPostProcessorsBeforeInitialization(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:409) ~[spring-beans-4.3.18.RELEASE.jar:4.3.18.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1626) ~[spring-beans-4.3.18.RELEASE.jar:4.3.18.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:555) ~[spring-beans-4.3.18.RELEASE.jar:4.3.18.RELEASE]
    ... 16 common frames omitted
```

I am currently making a spring boot application and the class containing the main  method has the `@EnableAspectJAutoProxy` annotation.

Edit 1:
The project is uploaded [here](https://gitlab.com/milinds.747/aop-poc)

Comment: What makes you think the aspect is the problem? Have you deleted it and checked what happens without it? And have you also tried removing the `@PostConstruct`? Another question is where "No ServerProperties registered" comes from. I find nothing about it on Google. Is is an error message specific to your application? Like so often, without an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) is is next to impossible to say anything intelligent about the possible root problem with the few fragments of information you provide.

Comment: The problem is encountered when I add the pointcut in the advice. I tried removing all the annotations related to aspectj. There was no error on adding `@EnableAspectJAutoProxy`, `@Aspect`, `@Pointcut`. Only on adding the given pointcut expression to the advice. Futhermore, `@Pointcut("within(some.example..*)")` works just fine. I too couldn't find anything on google, this was my last resort. The message is not specific to my application.

Comment: You can check the project [here](https://gitlab.com/milinds.747/aop-poc)

Answer (score 2):

I am not a Spring (Boot) user, but when running the MCVE to me it  looks like Spring Boot tries to apply your aspect to some of its own components. Just limit the scope of the pointcut to your own packages. For me this works:

```java
execution(public * some.example..*(..))
```

Or maybe you like this one better:

```java
within(some.example..*) && execution(public * *(..))
```

I also noticed in your POM that you use `org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-aop:2.0.3.RELEASE` but set the parent POM to `org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-parent:1.5.14.RELEASE`. You should harmonise that and use the same version.

Answer (score 0):

Please edit:

```
@Pointcut("execution(public * *(..))");
```

Comment: i know why ,edit @Before("execution(public * *(..))") to @Before("execution(public * com.liuhao.stu..*.*(..))").

Comment: I want to create a point cut without mentioning the base package. That's the reason I'd excluded base package from pointcut declaration. A workaround for this is to create a custom annotation and include all the sub/ packages based on that annotation.